# How to find a particular value in a string in js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, string

I have a data like this,

```
   var str = "#data time #city";
```

My goal is to make this as

```
 var str = <a src="www.test/data">#data</a> time <a src="www.test/city">city</a>
```

I mean in my string where ever I found # its next value i.e data should be set as a param to the link www.test/{{param}} and should be surrounded with a link.Can any one suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: string replace does not alter the original string.

Comment: consider using regular expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case, the [String.replace() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) will help you:

```js
var str = "#data time #city"
str = str.replace(/#(\S+)/g, '<a href="#$1">#$1</a>')
output.textContent = str
clickable.innerHTML = str
```

```css
#output { font-family: courier }
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="clickable"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks b4xter but I want those anchor tags clickable.

Comment: I inserted the generated HTML snipped in a `DIV` so you see its "clickable".

Answer (score 0):

The following code converts you data to the expected output.
The document.write(..) are for debug.

```js
var data='#data time #city';
var hashtags = data.match(/#\S+/g);   

document.write('before: ' + data + '</br>');

for (j = 0; j < hashtags.length; j++) {
    // remove # from hashtag
    var tag = hashtags[j].substring(1, hashtags[j].length); 
    // create the link
    var link = '< a src="www.test/' + tag + '>#' + tag + '< / a > ';
    
    // replace hashtag with link 
    data=data.replace(hashtags[j], link);
}

document.write('after: ' + data);
```

Comment: I've maintained the initial structure from your code but b4xter's answer is more elegant, you should use that one if possible.